SSH into RPI with VSCode, permission denied, unclear how to resolve
I would like to edit some python file that's on the sd card of my rpi.
Connecting via windows cmd to rpi when my windows laptop is connected via wifi goes well. Via the comment "ssh bdc@10.42.0.1".
But when I try to ssh into the rpi via vscode, I get the error below. I really cannot figure out why. It's strange that the password is immediately accepted via windows cmd wihle the permission gets denied after entering password in vscode.
Any ideas?
[16:21:00.004] Log Level: 2
[16:21:00.015] SSH Resolver called for "ssh-remote+7b22686f73744e616d65223a2231302e34322e302e31222c2275736572223a2273736820626463227d", attempt 1
[16:21:00.016] "remote.SSH.useLocalServer": false
[16:21:00.016] "remote.SSH.useExecServer": false
[16:21:00.016] "remote.SSH.showLoginTerminal": false
[16:21:00.017] "remote.SSH.remotePlatform": {"redvelvet.local":"linux","rpi1.local":"linux"}
[16:21:00.017] "remote.SSH.path": undefined
[16:21:00.017] "remote.SSH.configFile": undefined
[16:21:00.017] "remote.SSH.useFlock": true
[16:21:00.017] "remote.SSH.lockfilesInTmp": false
[16:21:00.017] "remote.SSH.localServerDownload": auto
[16:21:00.017] "remote.SSH.remoteServerListenOnSocket": false
[16:21:00.020] "remote.SSH.showLoginTerminal": false
[16:21:00.020] "remote.SSH.defaultExtensions": []
[16:21:00.020] "remote.SSH.loglevel": 2
[16:21:00.020] "remote.SSH.enableDynamicForwarding": true
[16:21:00.020] "remote.SSH.enableRemoteCommand": false
[16:21:00.020] "remote.SSH.serverPickPortsFromRange": {}
[16:21:00.020] "remote.SSH.serverInstallPath": {}
[16:21:00.023] VS Code version: 1.87.2
[16:21:00.023] Remote-SSH version: remote-ssh@0.109.0
[16:21:00.023] win32 x64
[16:21:00.025] SSH Resolver called for host: ssh bdc@10.42.0.1
[16:21:00.025] Setting up SSH remote "10.42.0.1"
[16:21:00.029] Using commit id "863d2581ecda6849923a2118d93a088b0745d9d6" and quality "stable" for server
[16:21:00.031] Install and start server if needed
[16:21:02.519] Checking ssh with "C:\WINDOWS\system32\ssh.exe -V"
[16:21:02.521] Got error from ssh: spawn C:\WINDOWS\system32\ssh.exe ENOENT
[16:21:02.521] Checking ssh with "C:\WINDOWS\ssh.exe -V"
[16:21:02.522] Got error from ssh: spawn C:\WINDOWS\ssh.exe ENOENT
[16:21:02.523] Checking ssh with "C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem\ssh.exe -V"
[16:21:02.524] Got error from ssh: spawn C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem\ssh.exe ENOENT
[16:21:02.524] Checking ssh with "C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\ssh.exe -V"
[16:21:02.525] Got error from ssh: spawn C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\ssh.exe ENOENT
[16:21:02.525] Checking ssh with "C:\WINDOWS\System32\OpenSSH\ssh.exe -V"
[16:21:02.571] > OpenSSH_for_Windows_8.6p1, LibreSSL 3.4.3

[16:21:02.576] Running script with connection command: "C:\WINDOWS\System32\OpenSSH\ssh.exe" -T -D 57020 "ssh bdc@10.42.0.1" bash
[16:21:02.579] Terminal shell path: C:\WINDOWS\System32\cmd.exe
[16:21:03.119] > ssh bdc@10.42.0.1's password:]0;C:\WINDOWS\System32\cmd.exe
[16:21:03.119] Got some output, clearing connection timeout
[16:21:03.119] Showing password prompt
[16:21:04.592] Got password response
[16:21:04.592] "install" wrote data to terminal: "***"
[16:21:04.636] > 
[16:21:07.754] > Permission denied, please try again.
> ssh bdc@10.42.0.1's password: 
[16:21:07.754] Showing password prompt
[16:21:09.280] Got password response
[16:21:09.280] "install" wrote data to terminal: "***"
[16:21:09.323] > 
[16:21:12.440] > Permission denied, please try again.
> ssh bdc@10.42.0.1's password: 
[16:21:12.441] Showing password prompt
[16:21:13.825] Got password response
[16:21:13.825] "install" wrote data to terminal: "***"
[16:21:13.876] > 
[16:21:16.994] > ssh bdc@10.42.0.1: Permission denied (publickey,password).
> The process tried to write to a nonexistent pipe.
[16:21:18.239] "install" terminal command done
[16:21:18.240] Install terminal quit with output: ssh bdc@10.42.0.1: Permission denied (publickey,password).
[16:21:18.240] Received install output: ssh bdc@10.42.0.1: Permission denied (publickey,password).
[16:21:18.243] Resolver error: Error: Permission denied (publickey,password).
    at g.Create (c:\Users\BootMR\.vscode\extensions\ms-vscode-remote.remote-ssh-0.109.0\out\extension.js:2:499734)
    at c:\Users\BootMR\.vscode\extensions\ms-vscode-remote.remote-ssh-0.109.0\out\extension.js:2:496342
    at t.handleInstallOutput (c:\Users\BootMR\.vscode\extensions\ms-vscode-remote.remote-ssh-0.109.0\out\extension.js:2:496978)
    at t.tryInstall (c:\Users\BootMR\.vscode\extensions\ms-vscode-remote.remote-ssh-0.109.0\out\extension.js:2:620589)
    at async c:\Users\BootMR\.vscode\extensions\ms-vscode-remote.remote-ssh-0.109.0\out\extension.js:2:580447
    at async t.withShowDetailsEvent (c:\Users\BootMR\.vscode\extensions\ms-vscode-remote.remote-ssh-0.109.0\out\extension.js:2:583753)
    at async k (c:\Users\BootMR\.vscode\extensions\ms-vscode-remote.remote-ssh-0.109.0\out\extension.js:2:577412)
    at async t.resolve (c:\Users\BootMR\.vscode\extensions\ms-vscode-remote.remote-ssh-0.109.0\out\extension.js:2:581124)
    at async c:\Users\BootMR\.vscode\extensions\ms-vscode-remote.remote-ssh-0.109.0\out\extension.js:2:847283
[16:21:18.248] ------

It's strange that the password is immediately accepted via windows cmd wihle the permission gets denied after entering password in vscode.
